# How to link local library with Autoconf

Tags: c++, makefile, autoconf

I'm try to implement a library, which is lying in the project folder, into a project which is build with `autoconf` (Makefiles created with `autoconf`). But I always get the error message, that the shared object can't be found.

> error while loading shared libraries: libgraphblas.so.2: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

Manual linking the files is working, also in another project without `autoconf` I am able to link the files, but I can't configure `autoconf` to make that automatically.

This is working Makefile

```
INCDIR  = ../include
LIBDIR  = ../lib

EXE     = tricky

LDFLAGS = -lgraphblas -Wl,-rpath,$(LIBDIR) -L$(LIBDIR)

CC      = g++ -std=c++11
CFLAGS  = -Wall -I$(INCDIR)

$(EXE): main.o reporter.o 
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

main.o: main.cc 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -g -c $<

reporter.o: reporter.cc $(HEADERS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -g -c $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ $(EXE)
```

In the Makefile.am for Autoconf I tried to replicate the Makefile

```
INCDIR  = ../resources/GraphBLAS/include
LIBDIR  = ../resources/GraphBLAS/lib

bin_PROGRAMS = programm

programm_SOURCES = ....

programm_CPPFLAGS = -I$(INCDIR)
programm_LDADD = -lgraphblas -L$(LIBDIR)
...
```

I get the following linking command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -g -O2  -L/home/user/Documents/Thesis/sparqlSim-

dav/resources/GraphBLAS/lib -o programm {Sources.o} -lgraphblas -

L../resources/GraphBLAS/lib
```

But I need this (Working when executed manual):

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -g -O2  -L/home/user/Documents/Thesis/sparqlSim-

dav/resources/GraphBLAS/lib -o programm {Sources.o} -lgraphblas -

L../resources/GraphBLAS/lib -Wl,-rpath,$(LIBDIR)
```

> Adding `"-Wl,-rpath,$(LIBDIR)"` to `LDFLAGS` does not work for me.

How to add `"-Wl,-rpath,$(LIBDIR)"` to the linking command created by `autoconf`?

Comment: Makefiles are not created by autoconf.  Autoconf does one thing only; it generates the configure script.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are doing; if you have a dependent library, you should build and install it.  If you install it in $HOME/lib, then you should add $HOME/lib to LDFLAGS when you invoke the configure script for your project.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Installing the library is not possible for me, so i have to use a precompiled one.

Comment: If it's precompiled, then you have no choice but to install it.   Put it somewhere, add that location to LDFLAGS when you run configure, problem solved.

Comment: @WilliamPursell thank you for that tip, I had another looking into the files and found my mistake. If was trying to run the compiled programm like: "./src/programm" and then the linking to the library is wrong...

Comment: Relative `-rpath` values are almost never what you want—although there is `${ORIGIN}`.